# Where is the code which rejects transactions with insuffisent balance?

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, c++

Simple question but I can’t find the answer again.
Where is the code which rejects transactions when the value of inputs is below the value of outputs (because I think to recall that check works like this) ?

And what’s the exact error message which is sent to the log in that case ?

Comment: Grepping in all files of the projects and all charsets for `\".*Balance` and `insufficient` is no help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code that checks that the inputs consumed are greater than the output

```
const CAmount value_out = tx.GetValueOut();
if (nValueIn < value_out) {
    return state.DoS(100, false, REJECT_INVALID, "bad-txns-in-belowout", false,
        strprintf("value in (%s) < value out (%s)", FormatMoney(nValueIn), FormatMoney(value_out)))
```

You can find it [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/consensus/tx_verify.cpp#L187).

Comment: And is this really the error message which state the balance is not enough on a third party transaction ? I think to recall the check is also in other functions.

Comment: This is the transaction checking function which sees that the value in > value out.

Comment: This function is then called in validation and mempool files https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?q=checktxinputs&unscoped_q=checktxinputs